# Is there anyway to check if n number of terms in a row of a matrix are equal in fortran?

Tags: fortran, fortran95

I was wondering if there was a quick way to have fortran look throughout a maxtrix’s rows and determine if n number of terms are equal.
I wasn’t able to find a question similar to mine and can’t find any help online.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean specifically. Can you give an example, or show us some things you've tried already?

Comment: @Ross if you run this: http://rextester.com/BSMM23214 then it'll be a matrix where none of the rows have more than two equal values (exclude column 1). My main concern is that if I make it more than 4 columns, the code won't account for different combinations where more than 2 terms in a row are the same.

Comment: I still don't understand. Can you provide a (small) sample data **in the question body** with the properties you want to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we consider a matrix of integers this comes at O(N³) cost, N being the dimension of the matrix. Essentially, for each row, you need to compare each element to each other element in that row, requiring O(N³) operations. You probably need to write that yourself, but its no big deal, loop over the rows and check for each separately, if some element appears n-times

```
integer :: M(N, N)              ! matrix to check
integer :: n, i, j, k, counter  ! flag if a value appears n times
logical :: appears

appears = .false.
do i = 1, N      ! loop over the rows
  do j = 1, N    ! loop over the entries
    counter = 1
    do k = j + 1, N
      ! check if the elements are the same, if yes, increase the counter
      ! exact implementation depends on type of M
      if(M(i, k) == M(i, j)) counter = counter + 1
      ! check if this element appears n times
      if(counter == n) appears = .true.
      ! or even more often?
      if(counter > n) appears = .false.
    end do 
  end do
end do
```

You can adapt that to your need, but you can do it like this.

Comment: What is this "abs(M[i][k] - M[i][j]) < 1e-12" ? Two problems: 1) this is not Fortran and 2) 1e-12 needs more explanation: When comparing real numbers you need to define what error tolerance you will allow. This will depend on the values in the matrix (say typical value) and the precision which these numbers are stored. 1E-12 may be reasonable if values are typically 1000. and numbers are stored in 8-byte format. An allowable error could be related to average (abs(values)) * epsilon (M) * 100, where 100 reflects the variability of values in the matrix (or rows) being considered.

Comment: OP never asked for real numbers. Also, the link provided shows an example of data with integers.

Comment: Right, I overlooked that. I switched to integers in the example and fixed the syntax

Comment: @KaiGuther I was able to adopt this to suit the task I needed to do, thanks for your help.

Comment: Fortran is case insensitive, so `n` and `N` cannot be different objects

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if there was a quick way to have fortran look throughout a maxtrix’s rows and determine if n number of terms are equal.

As far as I understood your problem, this is what you want:

- a function with the signature: `(integer(:), integer) -> logical`
- this function receives the 1-D array `line` and checks if there is any value that appears **at least** `n` times in the array
- the function is **not** supposed to indicate *what* or *how many* were those values, their positions or the exact number of repetitions

There are many ways to achieve this. *"What is the most efficient?"* It will depend on the specific conditions of your data, system, compiler, etc. To illustrate that, I came out with 3 different solutions. All of them give the correct answer, of course. You are advised to test each of them (or any other you come up with) with samples of your **real data**.

---

### Naive solution #1 - good 'ol do loops

This is the default algorithm. It traverses `line` and stores each value into the aggregator list `packed`, that has each distinct value found so far, along with how many times they appeared. In the moment that any value reaches `n` repetitions, the fuction returns `.true.`. If no values reached `n` repetitions, and there is no more chance to complete the predicate, it returns `.false.`.

I say *defalut* because it is the minimum *linear* algorith (that I figured out) based on good ol' `do` loops. This would probably be the best for the general case, if you have zero information about the nature of the data, system or even the programming language specifics. The aggregator is there to terminating the function as soon as the condition is met, but at the cost of an aditional list-traverse (on its length). If there are many different values in the data and `n` is large, the aggregator gets too long and the look-up can become an expensive operation. Also, there is almost no room for parallelism, vectorization and other optimizations.

```
! generic approach, with loops and aggregator
pure logical function has_at_least_n_repeated(line, n)
  integer, intent(in) :: line(:), n
  integer :: i, j, max_repetitions, qty_distincts
  ! packed(1,:) -> the distinct integers found so far
  ! packed(2,:) -> number of repetitions of each distinct integer so far
  integer :: packed(2, size(line) - n + 2)

  if(n < 1 .or. size(line) == 0) then
    has_at_least_n_repeated = .false.
  else if(n == 1) then
    has_at_least_n_repeated = .true.
  else
    packed(:, 1) = [line(1), 1]
    qty_distincts = 1
    max_repetitions = 1
    i = 1
    ! iterate until there aren't enough elements left to reach n repetitions
    outer: do, while(i - max_repetitions <= size(line) - n)
      i = i + 1
      ! test for a match on packed
      do j = 1, qty_distincts
        if(packed(1, j) == line(i)) then
          packed(2, j) = packed(2, j) + 1
          if(packed(2, j) == n) then
            has_at_least_n_repeated = .true.
            return
          end if
          max_repetitions = max(max_repetitions, packed(2, j))
          cycle outer
        end if
      end do
      ! add to packed
      qty_distincts = qty_distincts + 1
      packed(:, qty_distincts) = [line(i), 1]
    end do outer
    has_at_least_n_repeated = .false.
  end if
end
```

---

### Naive solution #2 - trying for some vectorization

This approach tries to take advantage of the *arraysh*-nature of Fortran and the fast implementations of the intrinsic functions. Instead of an internal do loop, there is a call to the intrinsic `count` with an array argument, allowing the compiler to do some vectorization. Also, if you hane any tool for parallelism or if you know how to work with coarrays (and your compiler supports), you could use this approach to implement them.

The disadvantage here is that the function does a scan for all elements, even if they appeared before. So, this is more suitable when there are many different posible values in your data, with few repetitions. Although, it would also be easy to add a cached list with the past values, and use the intrinsic `any`, passing the cache as a whole array.

```
! alternative approach, intrinsic functions without cache
pure logical function has_at_least_n_repeated(line, n)
  integer, intent(in) :: line(:), n
  Integer :: i

  if(n < 1 .or. size(line) == 0) then
    has_at_least_n_repeated = .false.
  else if(n == 1) then
    has_at_least_n_repeated = .true.
  else
    ! iterate until there aren't enough elements left to reach n repetitions
    do i = 1, size(line) - n + 1
      if(count(line(i + 1:) == line(i)) + 1 >= n) then
        has_at_least_n_repeated = .true.
        return
      end if
    end do
    has_at_least_n_repeated = .false.
  end if
end
```

---

### Naive solution #3 - functional style

This is my favorite (personal criteria). I like functional languages and I enjoy borrowing some aspects of it into imperative languages. This approach delegates the calculation to an internal auxiliary recursive function. There are no `do` loops here. On each function call, just a section of `line` is passed over as argument: a shorter array with only values not checked so far. No need for cache either.

To be honest, Fortran's support for recursion is far from great - there is no tail recursion, compilers usually implement low call-stack limit, and many auto-optimizations are prevented by recursion. Even though, the algorithm is smart, I love how it looks like and I wouldn't discard it before doing some tests and comparissons.

**Note**: Fortran does not allow nested procedures in the `contains` part of a main program. For it to work as presented, you'd need to put the function in a module, submodule or make it an external function. Other option would be extracting the nested function and making it a normal function in the same scope.

```
! functional approach, auxiliar recursive function and no loops
pure logical function has_at_least_n_repeated(line, n)
  integer, intent(in) :: line(:), n

  if(n < 1 .or. size(line) == 0) then
    has_at_least_n_repeated = .false.
  else if(n == 1) then
    has_at_least_n_repeated = .true.
  else
    has_at_least_n_repeated = aux(line)
  end if

contains
  ! on each iteration removes all entries of an element from array
  pure recursive function aux(section) result(out)
    integer, intent(in) :: section(:)
    logical :: out, mask(size(section))
    integer :: left
    mask = section /= section(1)
    left = count(mask)
    if(size(section) - left >= n) then
      out = .true.
    else if(n > left) then
      out = .false.
    else
      out = aux(pack(section, mask))
    end if
  end
end
```

---

### Conclusion

Do the tests before choosing a path to follow! I talked a litte here about my personal feeling on each approach and its implications, but it would be really nice if some of the *Fortran Gurus* on this site join the discussion and provide accurate information an critic.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a *pragmatic* alternative to the solutions @RodrigoRodrigues has already provided.  In the absence of any good evidence (the question is seriously underspecified) that we need to be concerned about asymptotic complexity and all that good stuff, here's a simple straightforward function which took me about 5 minutes to design, code, and test.

This function accepts a rank-1 array of integers and spits back a rank-1 array of integers, each element corresponding to the count of that element in the input array.  If that description confuses you, bear with me and read the code which is fairly simple:

```
FUNCTION get_counts(arr) RESULT(rslt)
  INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(in) :: arr
  INTEGER, DIMENSION(SIZE(arr)) :: rslt
  INTEGER :: ix
  DO ix = 1, SIZE(arr)
     rslt(ix) = COUNT(arr(ix)==arr)
  END DO
END FUNCTION get_counts
```

For the input array `[1,1,2,3,4,1,5]` it returns `[3,3,1,1,1,3,1]`.  If OP wants to use this as the basis of a function to see if there is any value which occurs `n` times then OP could write

```
any(get_counts(rank_1_integer_array)==n)
```

If OP is concerned to know what elements occur `n` times then it is fairly straightforward to use the result of `get_counts` to refer back to the original array to extract that element.

This solution is *pragmatic* in the sense that it is parsimonious with *my* time rather than with the computer's time.  My solution is somewhat wasteful of space, which may be an issue for very large input arrays. Any of Rodrigo's solutions may outperform mine, in both time and space, in the limit.

Comment: If I make your function elemental and nest it inside a function declared like those I presented, with a body containing just `has_at_least_n_repeated = n > 0 .and. any(get_counts(line) >= n)`, that could be fairly a winner in a parallel scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I took the question to mean that it was to be determined whether any value in a row was repeated at least `n` times. To figure this out I chose to sort a copy of each row using [qsort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/) from the C standard library and then it's easy to find the lengths of each run of values.

```
module sortrow
   use ISO_C_BINDING
   implicit none
   interface
      subroutine qsort(base, num, size, compar) bind(C,name='qsort')
         import
         implicit none
         integer base(*)
         integer(C_SIZE_T), value :: num, size
         procedure(icompar) compar
      end subroutine qsort
   end interface
   contains
      function icompar(p1, p2) bind(C)
         integer(C_INT) icompar
         integer p1, p2
         select case(p1-p2)
            case(:-1)
               icompar = -1
            case(0)
               icompar = 0
            case(1:)
               icompar = 1
         end select
      end function icompar
end module sortrow

program main
   use sortrow
   implicit none
   integer, parameter :: M = 3, N = 10
   integer i, j
   integer array(M,N)
   real harvest
   integer, allocatable :: row(:)
   integer current, maxMatch

   call random_seed
   do i = 1, M
      do j = 1, N
         call random_number(harvest)
         array(i,j) = harvest*3
      end do
   end do
   do i = 1, M
      row = array(i,:)
      call qsort(row, int(N,C_SIZE_T), C_SIZEOF(array(1,1)), icompar)
      maxMatch = 0
      current = 1
      do j = 2, N
         if(row(j) == row(j-1)) then
            current = current+1
         else
            current = 1
         end if
         maxMatch = max(maxMatch,current)
      end do
      write(*,'(*(g0:1x))') array(i,:),'maxMatch =',maxMatch
   end do
end program main
```

Sample run:

```
0 0 0 2 0 2 1 1 1 0 maxMatch = 5
2 1 2 1 0 1 2 1 2 0 maxMatch = 4
0 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 1 1 maxMatch = 5
```